# Infimum of absolute values versus absolute value of infimum

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb R$.

Is there a nice proof of the inequality
$\displaystyle\inf_{a\in A} |a|\le|\inf_{a\in A} a|$?

The only proof I know is, though not very difficult, annoying because it requires case analysis (three cases, depending on where $\inf a$ is in comparison to $-\inf_{a\ge 0} a$ and $0$).  I wonder if I'm overlooking a nice calculational proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although we still have to separate cases, maybe this is simple enough. We have two cases:

1) If $A$ has some element $a_0\leq 0$, then $\inf_{a\in A}a\leq a_0\leq0$, thus
$$\inf_{a\in A}|a|\leq |a_0|=-a_0\leq -\inf_{a\in A}a\leq |\inf_{a\in A}a|.$$

2) If all elements of $A$ are positive, then
$$\inf_{a\in A}|a|=\inf_{a\in A}a=|\inf_{a\in A}a|.$$

Comment: Simple enough for me!